# SQL Server alert mechanism whenever an identity column data type value is about to reach its maximum limit

Tags: sql-server

I just want to monitor where it throw an alert whenever an identity column data type value is about to reach its maximum limit.

Like, I have a 'A' table and that table has an integer identity `Id` with 2,147,483,000 rows. As we know, SQL Server integer limit is +-2,147,483,647

Integer `Id` identity column is about to reach its maximum limit.

I tried to query all db tables with max(integer data types) function,  and compare with own limits. But that is quite costly.

I need list of identity column data type with their table name that value about to reach its maximum limit.

İs there any way of this like built-in alert mechanism that automatically notifies or I need to create a job that query tables with max function etc.

Comment: Do you also need do consider `SEQUENCE`s?

Answer (score 8):

You should quite easily be able to get that information from the `sys.identity_columns` system catalog view.

Try a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    IdColumnName = ic.name,
    IdColumnType = ty.name,
    ic.seed_value,
    ic.increment_value,
    ic.last_value
FROM 
    sys.identity_columns ic
INNER JOIN
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.types ty ON ty.user_type_id = ic.user_type_id
```

and get a result along those lines here:

| TableName | IdColumnName | IdColumnType | seed_value | increment_value | last_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RegionsModel | id | int | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| Campaign | CampaignId | int | 1000 | 1 | 1002 |
| Manufacturer | Id | int | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| Car | Id | int | 1 | 1 | 9 |
| Sale | Id | int | 1 | 1 | 9 |
| Country | CountryID | int | 1 | 1 | 18 |
| MinPerson | ID | int | 1 | 1 | 13 |

You can easily schedule this query to be run on a regular basis, and flag a warning, when `last_value` goes over a threshold value you can define.

Read all about `sys.identity_columns` in your [trusted official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-identity-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This answer is useful, appreciate it

Comment: If an answer is useful, @steakburgerr , the  you should use the upvote feature as comments can be removed (especially conversational comments). [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ThomA - Upvoting requires 15 rep. steakburgerr has 1. You can accept an answer thougth!

Comment: That's handy, I always go for dbcc checkident